# Rails 4 - "Validate" on a single column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to make a validation before updating my record. 
The validation should trigger only when a single column's value has changed.

```
  def manage_only_subordinates_schedules
    current_user = User.current
    if !current_user.manager_of(self.created_by,true)
      self.errors.add(:base, "Vous ne pouvez pas verrouiller une programmation qui a été vérouillée par un utilisateur de grade supérieur")
      return false
    end
  end

 private  :manage_only_subordinates_schedules
 validate :manage_only_subordinates_schedules, :on => :update
```

Is there any way we can do something like this ?

```
validate :manage_only_subordinates_schedules, :on => :update, :columns => [:locked]
```

Comment: `validate :manage_only_subordinates_schedules, on: :update, if: "locked.changed?"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Votre code devrait être:

```
#app/models/model.rb
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :manage_only_subordinates_schedules, on: :update, if: "locked.changed?"

  private

  def manage_only_subordinates_schedules
    current_user = User.current
    self.errors.add(:base, "Vous ne pouvez pas verrouiller une programmation qui a été vérouillée par un utilisateur de grade supérieur") unless current_user.manager_of(self.created_by,true)
  end
end
```

Regarde [Using a string with `if` and `unless`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-string-with-if-and-unless)

> You can also use a string that will be evaluated using eval and needs to contain valid Ruby code. You should use this option only when the string represents a really short condition.

---

As a side note, you should look at authorization, especially with [`CanCanCan`](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) or `Pundit`:

```
#Gemfile 
gem "cancancan"

#app/models/ability.rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    can :manage, Model do |model|
      user.manager_of(model.created_by, true)
    end
  end
end

#app/views/models/show.html.erb
<% # do something if can? :manage, Model %>
```

Whilst not a replacement for the validation, it will give you the ability to manage the flow so that only managers can use it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to check out [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html). Let's say you have a `Book` model and you want to have a validation when the `title` changed:

`validate :call_this_method, if: :title_changed?`